# How can I call method in global vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, global, vue-component, vuex

I have root vue component app.js:

```
...
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ...
    methods: {
        modalShow: function(target, id=null, message=null){
           ...
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

I have a child component like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail"
                   title="Add photo" 
                   @click="modalShow('modal-add-photo', product.id)"
                > 
                    <span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span> 
                </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `modalShow` method is in the root. How can I call it from the child?

If the code above is executed now, I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "modalShow" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.

Comment: Do you mean the root Vue? Is your component a direct child of the root?

Comment: @Bert Evans, Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `modalShow` method down to the child component.

```
<child :modal-show="modalShow"></child>

export default {
  props:["modalShow"]
}
```

Then you can use the method in the child.

Comment: @TrendingNews You don't need to tag me. If it's a question tagged with Vue I will see it :)

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I will not tag you again